# The distribution of processing threads on the processor cores

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel

The operating system independently distributes the processing of threads over the processor cores. The program has two threads. Initially, both threads are not loaded with work and are processed by one core. Later they are loaded with work. Will the operating system transfer the processing of one thread to another processor core?

Comment: Your question is vague.  For example, you say "the operating system," but you don't say _what_ operating system.  Different operating systems can have different scheduling policies, and sometimes, different instances of the _same_ operating system can have different thread scheduling policies.

Comment: @jameslarge Most of all I'm interested in two operating systems: ubuntu 14 (and above) and Win (XP and above, including server ones).

Comment: For Linux, you can start by reading the `man 7 sched` man page.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html  I know less about Windows.  Maybe look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685096.aspx  For general information, you could look at Wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)

Comment: @jameslarge I am not interested in the programming (tuning) of the behavior stated in the question. I'm interested in how the operating system will behave in the case that is stated in the question. I know that can assign the processing of a thread to the processor core. But the question about other. In any case, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: How the operating system will behave depends on the "tuning".  Also, It's not just tuning.  Both Linux and Windows offer several completely different _algorithms_ for choosing which thread gets to run on which processor.

Comment: Part of the reason I can not answer your question is, I don't understand it.  I don't know what you mean when you talk about threads that are "loaded with work."  Are you talking about the average CPU time recently used by the thread?  or something else?  I don't know what you mean by "processed by one core."  Are you talking about threads that have been assigned an _affinity_ for a particular CPU? or something else?